# getQty() giving fatal error in magento 1.9

Tags: php, collections, magento-1.9, quotes

I am trying to get the collection based on ***product*** and ***quote Id*** using,

```
$quotecollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quoteId)->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$product_id);

$quotecollectionaArr =  $quotecollection->getData();
echo $quotecollection->getQty();
```

which gives the following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::getQty() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs....

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getFirstItem()`

```
  $quotecollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quoteId)->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$product_id)->getFirstItem();
  echo $quotecollection->getQty();
```